# How can I write this AR equation in latex

Tags: math-mode, equations

How can I write this equation in Latex? 
I have just started out writing my first paper, and I'd appreciate any kind of help. 
[image: AR equation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:AR}
y_i = c + \sum_{i=1}^{p}\varphi_i y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t = \dots
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

on showed way you should finish your equation yourself. please read some introductory text about `latex`, for example for math [LaTeX/Mathematics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics)